# Communication between two microservices in JHipster using JWT

Tags: spring-security, jwt, microservices, jhipster

I'm building a small microservice-based webapp using JHipster with JWT authorization. The Architecture is simple, one gateway and two services with repositories. The problem that I had for the last few hours is the communication between the two backend-services.

At first, I tried to find a token on the services themself, but couldn't find it. If I just missed it in all the docs (quite overwhelming when beginning with the full stack :P), I would be happy to revert my changes and use the predefined token.

My second approach was that each service will authorize itself with the gateway at PostConstruct and save the token in memory to use it each API call. It works without a problem, but I find it hard to believe that this functionality is not already programmed in JHipster.

So my question is whether my approach is usual? If neither is true and there are some best-practices for it, I'm also interested in them.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the use case.

For user requests, a common approach is: the calling service forwards the token it received to the other service without going through the gateway suing `@AuthorizedFeignClient`.

For background tasks like scheduled jobs, your approach can be applied or you could also issue long life tokens as long as they have limited permissions through roles. This way you don't have to go through gateway.

Keycloak's [offline tokens](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.2/server_admin/topics/sessions/offline.html) approach could also inspire you.